# how to import a file from different folder in K6

Tags: k6

im trying to import a file from different folder but it gives me an error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5SEu.png)

```
Error:

ERROR[0000] GoError: The moduleSpecifier "../data/GetServerToken" couldn't be found on local disk. Make sure that you've specified the right path to the file. If you're running k6 using the Docker image make sure you have mounted the local directory (-v /local/path/:/inside/docker/path) containing your script and modules so that they're accessible by k6 from inside of the container, see https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/modules#using-local-modules-with-docker.
        at go.k6.io/k6/js.(*requireImpl).require-fm (native)
        at file:///C:/Users/SameeraSenarath/OneDrive/GTN-Performance/GTN-Fintech-K6/k6-api-framework/src/tests/script-browser.js:3:0(28)  hint="script exception"
```

this is the run command i used "k6 run \src\tests\script-browser.js"

Comment: You are missing the `.js` extension in your import. The file name is `GetServerToken.js`, but you try to import a file with name `GetServerToken`. The latter does not exist.

Comment: @knittl thank you, you helped me to solve the issue. You should post an answer instead of a comment, then yours will be accepted.

Comment: @Phi no, that's not an answer, that's "not reproducible or was caused by a typo". This question should be closed/deleted, it doesn't help future visitors

Comment: @knittl this might be considered as a typo. However, in my case, I am not good at javascript and the import was suggested by vscode. I got the same error then I found this question. This is really helpful for those who is just like me. So sorry but I disagree when you said "it doesn't help future visitors". Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> The moduleSpecifier "../data/GetServerToken" couldn't be found on local disk.

For imports of local files, you need to provide the proper path to the file. This means that the file name must include the extension:

```
import { createAssertion } from '../data/GetServerToken.js';
```